# Using Python to Submit Multiple Jobs to a Supercomputer

Tags: python, bash, import, glob, submission

I am currently using a supercomputer for various quantum mechanical calculations. There are a large number of files I need to submit at any given time (280 separate submisions).  I am trying to use python to automate this process but have little experience with using python to run a separate submission script.  The submission script I am using (named subOrca_mpi.sh) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
string=".inp"
root="${1%$string}"

#if [ -z $1 ]
#then
#  echo 'Usage: subGamess.sh <jobinput>'
#  exit 1
#fi

#if [ ! -f ./$root.inp ]
#then
#  echo '<jobinput> does not look like an Orca input \(*.inp\)'
#  exit 1
#fi

if [ -f $root.slurm ]
then
   rm $root.slurm
fi

echo '#!/bin/bash'>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --job-name='$root>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --output='$root'.out'>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --nodes=1'>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12 '>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --time=0-48:00:00 '>>$root.slurm
echo '#SBATCH --cluster=smp'>>$root.slurm

echo 'cd $SBATCH_O_WORKDIR'>>$root.slurm
echo 'module purge'>>$root.slurm
echo 'module load orca/3.0.3'>>$root.slurm

echo 'files=('>>$root.slurm
echo  $root'.inp'>>$root.slurm
echo ')'>>$root.slurm
echo 'for i in ${files[@]}; do'>>$root.slurm
echo '     sbcast $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/$i $SLURM_SCRATCH/$i'>>$root.slurm
echo 'done'>>$root.slurm

echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi-
1.10/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'>>$root.slurm
echo 'export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi-1.10/bin:$PATH'>>$root.slurm

echo 'cd $SLURM_SCRATCH'>>$root.slurm

echo '$(which orca) '$root'.inp'>>$root.slurm
echo 'cp $SLURM_SCRATCH/*.{gbw,prop} $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR'>>$root.slurm

sbatch $root.slurm

exit
```

From what I've been told, I will need to import os, but I'm essentially lost from there. The only code I have thus far is:

```
import os
import glob
def orcasubmit():
    for filename in glob.glob('*.inp'):
        #execute subOrca_mpi.sh for all input files in given folder

orcasubmit()
```

Any input would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html This is the module you need.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two alternatives here. The first one, as you've probably guessed, is using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). You can do that like this:

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.inp'):
    os.system('./' + filename) # assuming these files lie in the same directory
```

Alternatively, you may use the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) module, and I recommend this one.

```
from subprocess import Popen
for filename in glob.glob('*.inp'):
    process = Popen(['/bin/bash', filename])
```

Comment: `subprocess.check_output()` is probably enough for the OP and somewhat easier to grasp/use.

Comment: @Anthon Won't that block till the command runs? OP would want this to dispatch in the background. This would do nicely.

Comment: I'm going to give the first option a try and see how that works. Thank you

Comment: @celani99 Sure, if it helps/doesn't, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @coldspeed, I will.

Comment: @coldspeed, I realized why it wasn't working -- I had forgotten a star in `glob.glob('*.inp')`, so I fixed that and the `os.system` option you provided worked perfectly.  In your response, however, there is no star and I wasn't able to edit it because the edit was less than 6 characters. If you could edit that, it'd be great.

Comment: @celani99 Done, much appreciated. Glad to know you figured it out :)